# Read .xlsx in .txt or .csv format with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to read a `.xlsx` file in `.txt` or `.csv` format with Python? Looking for a way to read an `.xlsx` file while preserving number formatting (e.g., $45.890924). Searched around and could not find a viable module, and creating a style converter would be next to impossible with my Python skill level.

A few helpful notes, Pandas would not be an option because it automatically wipes the number formatting, and I cannot classify the column's format in advance since one column can contain 20+ different number formats.

Comment: @OlvinRoght thank you for commenting. The issue is that `openpyxl` and `pandas` do not preserve the number formatting as mentioned above in the helpful notes section.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I understand you can extract the style format, but as mentioned in the last sentence of the first paragraph, this is not possible with my current python skill level.

Comment: What's your final task? I don't understand what do you mean under 20+ different formats. Number, decimal number, currency, percent ... what else?

Comment: @OlvinRoght it's an unstructured database. There can be a range of custom formats from currency, to comma placement, to rounding, to various date formats based on geo-location, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`openpyxl` stores the content of the cell in `value` and the formatting in `number_format` (and in a few other properties for alignment, color, font, border, etc). So you *could* interpret the Excel format code and translate it to Python format - but

1. of course a few format properties do not make sense in CSV: e.g. you cannot make negative numbers red in a CSV
2. While Excel format codes for dates and times are relatively easy to handle, those for numbers can be very tricky to decipher. As an example this is the standard currency format string for Euro:

```
'_-* #,##0.00\ [$€-410]_-;\-* #,##0.00\ [$€-410]_-;_-* "-"??\ [$€-410]_-;_-@_-'
```

All that said, making a translator is not impossible. Below is a simple function to translate Excel date format strings to Python's `strftime()` directives.

```
def date_xl2py(dt, xlcode):
    xl2py = {
        'yy' : '%y',
        'yyyy' : '%Y',
        'm' : '%m', ##always zero-padded
        'mm' : '%m',
        'mmm' : '%b',
        'mmmm' : '%B',
        'mmmmm' : '%b', ##no single letter form
        'd' : '%d', ##always zero-padded
        'dd' : '%d',
        'ddd' : '%a',
        'dddd' : '%A',
        '%' : '%%' ##escape the % char
        }
    pycode = []
    for xlpart in findall(r'[d|m|y|h|s]+|.|(".+")', xlcode):
        if xlpart in xl2py:
            pycode.append(xl2py[xlpart])
        else:
            pycode.append(xlpart)
    return ''.join(pycode)

dt = datetime(2022,7,12,15,56)
dt.strftime(date_xl2py(dt, 'ddd, mmmm dd, yyyy'))          
'Tue, July 12, 2022'
```

Please note, I didn't take into account the specification of a locale.

Also, Excel offers three (rather useless) date formatting options that are not available in Python (see comments in the code): I just mapped them to the most similar option available.

And finally, if you were to add time formats, you would need to handle the fact that "mm" may be months or minutes in Excel, and select the right option based on context.